# Some attributes ignored when use subfields in a relationship

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-backpack

I'm using this relationship in a project.

```
        $this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'laundryItems',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'tab'  => 'Pieza a enviar',
            'label' => 'Piezas en el envío',
            // ..
            'subfields' => [

                [
                    'name' => 'qty',
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'label' => 'Cantidad TOTAL',
                    'hint'  => 'Total de piezas enviadas/recibidas',
                    'wrapper' => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-3',
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'qtyDamaged',
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'label' => 'Cantidad Dañadas',
                    'hint'  => 'De las recibidas, cuántas dañadas',
                    'wrapper' => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-3',
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'qtyDirty',
                    'type' => 'number',
                    'label' => 'Cantidad Sucias',
                    'hint'  => 'De las recibidas, cuántas sucias',
                    'wrapper' => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-3',
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'name' => 'comment',
                    'label' => 'Comentario',
                    'type' => 'textarea',
                    'wrapper' => [
                        'class' => 'form-group col-md-6',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]);
```

which is working perfectly well. But now I want to use ***options*** and ***attribute*** but both are ignored until I delete the subfields property

So if I use

```
$this->crud->addField([
            'name' => 'laundryItems',
            'type' => 'relationship',
            'tab'  => 'Pieza a enviar',
            'label' => 'Piezas en el envío',
            'attribute' => 'pmsCode',
        ]);
```

attribute is applied, but if I add the subfields again, then not. That doesn't make any sense. I deleted the view cache but still the same issue.

#### PHP VERSION:

PHP 8.2.15 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2024 14:17:05) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.15, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.15, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

#### LARAVEL VERSION:

10.44.0.0

#### BACKPACK PACKAGE VERSIONS:

backpack/backupmanager: v5.0.0
backpack/basset: 1.2.2
backpack/crud: 6.6.3
backpack/devtools: 3.0.4
backpack/editable-columns: 3.0.5
backpack/generators: v4.0.3
backpack/logmanager: v5.0.1
backpack/permissionmanager: 7.1.1
backpack/pro: 2.1.3
backpack/settings: 3.1.0
backpack/theme-coreuiv2: 1.2.3
backpack/theme-coreuiv4: 1.1.1
backpack/theme-tabler: 1.2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my self. It's very well documented, if you need to modify the primary select you have to use the attribute **pivotSelect**
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-fields#configuring-the-pivot-select-field

```
'pivotSelect'=> [
                'options' => function($model) {
                    return $model->where('active', 1);
                },
                'attribute' => 'pmsCode'
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `attribute` property is used to specify `column` when we want a **select dropdown** from another table.

We use `subfields` when to show a form to create related table items directly from the CRUD.

If you want both in the same CRUD, you should consider [creating related entries in a modal - using the InlineCreate Operation.](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-fields#create-related-entries-in-a-modal-using-the-inlinecreate-operati)

In your case, it looks like you want a dropdown to select items & define quantity. This is similar to an example defined in the docs here:

https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/6.x/crud-fields#save-additional-data-to-pivot-table
[image]

Comment: I use a pivot table and I want to use attribute in order to use a function in the model in order to return a composed name based on two fields and also use "options", both attributes are documented for the relationship field type. I should be able to use it even using a pivot table.